# Are Ghazan and Ming-hua a couple?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

Ghazan and Ming-hua are villians from The Legend of Korra that are trying to end the avatar cycle along with Zaheer and P'li. Their gang is called the Red Lotus.

Answer (score 2):

The only time the topic is approached is in the episode "Long Live the Queen."

While captured, Bolin entertains himself by making guesses about Ghazan.

> Bolin: You were raised by an older sister, your mustache grew in when you were ten and I'm sensing - just sensing - an unspoken attraction between you two.
>
> Ghazan: Two out of three. Not bad.

The scene is intentionally ambiguous, with Ghazan never clarifying which ones are true. Though Michael Dante DiMartino, co-creator and executive producer of *Legend of Korra*, has stated [that he thinks the mustache one is accurate](https://avatar.fandom.com/f/p/2330653173481622156/r/2332066603597974131).

[image]

Upon hearing the "unspoken attraction" guess, Ghazan's eyes open bigger and Ming-Hua looks annoyed. Though again, it's open to interpretation what all that means.

Overall, the fact that a relationship is never mentioned suggests that there probably isn't one. And if Bolin is accurate in sensing something between them, it's only an "unspoken attraction," not a relationship.